# How to make bootstrap navlink active in dynamically generated for loop in django template

Tags: python, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am trying to make a tag navlink active in for loop django template. Every link is passing id, base on id matching i would like make nav-link active.

This is my Template html page, this is for loop and here i am checking condition to make nav-link active. I am not able to highlight the nav-link.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core_app:store' 'all' %}">All</a>
    </li>
  {% for type in store_type %}
     {% if type.id == typeid %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'core_app:store' type.id %}">{{type.name}}</a>
        </li>
     {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core_app:store' type.id %}">{{type.name}}</a>
        </li>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is my View code
Here i am getting all `store_type` and base on link click and passing id and i am extracting type of store. Then i would like to highlight my nav-link active base on conditional matching

```
def store(request, id):
    if id == "all":
        store_list = Store.objects.all().order_by('id')
    else:
        store_list = Store.objects.all().filter(store_type=int(id)).order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'core_app/store/all_store.html', {'stores': store_list, 'typeid': id, "store": "active", 'store_list': 'active', 'store_type': StoreType.objects.all()})
```

Model (Store has StoreType)

```
class StoreType(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
      ...
      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

class Store(model.Model):
      store_type = models.ForeignKey(...)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
      ...
```

Please help me to fix this or Suggest me better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code typeid is a string, while type.id is an integer, just cast it as an integer and it should work:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link {% if typeid|int == 0 %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'core_app:store' 'all' %}">All</a>
    </li>
  {% for type in store_type %}
     {% if type.id == typeid|int %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'core_app:store' type.id %}">{{type.name}}</a>
        </li>
     {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core_app:store' type.id %}">{{type.name}}</a>
        </li>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: oh my bad! thank a lot,  i got error (TemplateSyntax error -  invalid filter: 'int') using this {% if type.id == typeid|int %} so i changed like this {% if type.id|stringformat:'s' == typeid %}. Thank you.